# How to trigger Search as you type suggestion function in JS?

Tags: javascript

I have a function build in Javascript. This function shows suggestion when someone types anything in search-box. I want to call this function when anything is being typed in the box. How can I do this using Javascript?

Comment: Create a listener for the event `change` or `keyup` on your input component, and call your function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the [`eventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener).

Assign it to your input field and fire your function every time the user types something:

```js
function search() {
  /** Your actual search function */
  console.log("Searching...");
}
// Fire a specified function every time the user types something in the input field
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('keyup', search);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search">
```

Comment: Was getting error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'addEventListener' of null [duplicate]`
This worked:
`$(document).on("input", "search", function () {
    newSearch();
});`